# sed: why the commands after curly bracket is not executed?

Tags: sed

`$ cat thegeekstuff.txt`

```
#Linux
        Administration
        Scripting
        Tips and Tricks

#Windows
        Administration

#Database
        Mysql
        Mysql
        Oracle
        Queries
        Mysql
        Procedures
```

`$ sed -n '/Mysql/{g;1!p;};h' thegeekstuff.tx`

```
#Database
#Database
        Queries
```

this means the h command is not executed for lines matching the pattern. But my impression is that commands with no address selection applies to every line. Could someone explain why it behave like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is not working? Your command works exactly what it has been told.

`{..}` are for [grouping](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35)

`/Mysql/` - This is the `regex` you provide. So commands in `{..}` will only run for the line where they see `Mysql`.

On the contrary, `h` will run for every line. `h` is copying your pattern space to hold buffer.

When your grouping sees the line with `Mysql` they copy what was on the hold space to pattern space. See the line before `Mysql`. As a result `Database` is printed. For subsequent line same thing happens. Your pattern space is still `Database` from the `g` command.

Lastly, it prints `queries` since that was the line before `Mysql` that was captured by `h` command to your hold buffer and printed back by your grouping statements.

Comment: let us focus on these 3 lines:
#Database
   Mysql 
   Mysql

when sed scan to the first Mysql line, it retrieve from the hold space "#Database", and then it should save the current line "Mysql" in hold space, and when it scan the second "Mysql", the value retrieved from hold space should be "Mysql" instead of "#Database"

Comment: When first `Mysql` line is seen the `g` command deletes your pattern space and replaces the content from hold space which is `#Database`. Once grouping is completed `h` which runs for every line sees the pattern space as `#Database` instead of `Mysql` and puts it back to hold space. For next `Mysql` the `g` command grabs the hold space back which was `#Database` and hence you don't see `Mysql` but `#Database` printed out.

Answer (score 3):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed): explanation

```
sed -n '/Mysql/{g;1!p;};h'

h  # copy pattern space to hold space

/Mysql/{ # commands if the first pattern /Mysql/ is found
    g  # copy hold space to pattern space, in first /Mysql/ "#Database" is in hold space from the last line "h" command
    1!p # print the pattern space except in line #1, "#Database" is printed
 h # copy pattern space "#Database" to hold space

 /Mysql/{ # commands if the second pattern /Mysql/ is found
    g  # copy hold space to pattern space, in second /Mysql/ "#Database" is again in hold space from last "h" command
    1!p # print the pattern space except in line #1, "#Database" is printed again
  h # copy pattern space "#Database" to hold space

 /Mysql/{ # commands if the third pattern /Mysql/ is found
    g  # copy hold space to pattern space, in third /Mysql/ is "Queries" in hold space from last line "h" command
    1!p # print the pattern space except in line #1, "Query" is printed now
  h # copy pattern space to hold space
} end program
```

Comment: I understand your explainantion. but my question remains.

Comment: Question "Could someone explain why it behave like this?" should be answered. The `h` command is executed for every line.

Comment: I understand your explainantion. but my question remains. for each line, the program retrieve the previous line saved in the hold space. My question is when two lines of "Mysql" appear next to each other, when sed scan the second Mysql, the g command should get from the hold space the first Mysql instead of the line before it(#Database). this means when a match occured, the commmands in {} are executed and then control goes back to the top, h is not executed. why?

Comment: Obviously, you didn't read my explanation :). When `g` is executed, hold space "#Database" is copied to pattern space and **deletes** pattern space with "Mysql".

Comment: My apology :-). sed has a lot of details to attend to.

Comment: No matter :=) I can suggest a good text book: [Learn sed - "Definitive Guide to sed"](http://sed-book.com/).